How to git diff on an Azure DevOps CI pipeline with more than one repository
There are a few helpful [questions and answers][1] online,
[1]: How to git diff on a Azure CI pipeline, but they seem to be working in a single-repository environment. I'm using one git repository for the project source, another for a department-wide YAML code repo that covers several projects.
My current challenge is getting a list of changed files as a result of a PullRequest, IndividualCI, or BatchCI Build.Reason for the product repo. The list is needed for a CI static code analysis.
Using git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD (or HEAD~ HEAD or @~ @) all give me fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
With two repositories, the Build.SourceDirectory gets the name of the repositories appended, but I haven't been able to find for to use that information (e.g. \agent\_work\1\s\foo) in or before the git diff call.
Has anyone come across that problem, or any suggestions for a solution?

Assuming you have defined additional repository resource(s) in your YAML pipeline to be consumed together with the self repo, and according to the document,

Unless a path is specified in the checkout step, source code is placed in a default directory. This directory is different depending on whether you are checking out a single repository or multiple repositories.
Multiple repositories: If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of s in (Agent.BuildDirectory). If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is C:\agent\_work\1 and your repositories are named tools and code, your code is checked out to C:\agent\_work\1\s\tools and C:\agent\_work\1\s\code,

Therefore, you may try the sample YAML pipeline below to run git diff in different repo paths on that agent machine.
resources:
 repositories:
   - repository: RepoA
     name: RepoA
     type: git

variables:
  RepoA.name: $[ resources.repositories.RepoA.name ]
  RepoA.ref: $[ resources.repositories.RepoA.ref ]
  RepoA.version: $[ resources.repositories.RepoA.version ]

steps:
# Set fetchDepth as 0 to disable the dault shallow fetch 1
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
- checkout: RepoA
  fetchDepth: 0
- script: |
    echo "================ 1. Show file structure in Pipeline.Workspace ================"
    tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    
    echo "================ 2. Show self repo info and run git diff ================"
    cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/$(Build.Repository.Name)
    echo "self repo name: $(Build.Repository.Name)"
    echo "self repo ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    echo "self repo commit version: $(Build.SourceVersion)"
    git diff --name-only $(Build.SourceVersion)^ $(Build.SourceVersion)
    
    echo "================ 3. Show $(RepoA.name) info and run git diff ================"
    cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/$(RepoA.name)
    echo "RepoA name: $(RepoA.name)"
    echo "RepoA ref: $(RepoA.ref)"
    echo "RepoA commit version: $(RepoA.version)"
    git diff --name-only $(RepoA.version)^ $(RepoA.version)
  displayName: Run git diff in multiple repo paths



Thanks, @https://alvin-zhao-msft, that's almost the solution, and most helpful!
If I commit a file to project FOO, git diff HEAD^ HEAD shows identical values for HEAD^ and HEAD, so there's no difference. But if I use HEAD~ HEAD instead, it does work. If I understand the git documentation correctly, I should be using ^ and not ~, but only the latter is working.

Hi @HaraldJ, Glad to help. Per the follow-up query, generally speaking, for a simple linear commit history, HEAD^ and HEAD~ are equivalent. However, the caret (^) syntax allows for more specific parent references in merge commits, whereas the tilde (~) syntax is used for specifying the number of commits to go back in the history. For further discussions it would be another topic than the issue we discussed in this thread to run git diff in the repective repo paths.

I would suggest you creat a new ticket with a simplified scenario to dirrectly run the git diff command after checking out your foo repo and please let us know how you commited the file,  by a PR, what  were the source and taget branches and what was the merge type. Do share some screenshots to help understand how the issue is reproduced. For my sample repo, git diff --name-only $(RepoA.version)^ $(RepoA.version) and git diff --name-only $(RepoA.version)~ $(RepoA.version) produced the same result.

Let's resolve an issue at a time, shall we? Happy coding and cheers!

Thanks again! I used build reason IndividualCI, for case PullRequest the caret might be the right version, then it would be a simple if/else to get the differences for both.

@HaraldJ, Appreciate your taking time to share the update.

May I know if the answer can solve the issue in this post? Thx for the sharing which may help other community members with similar concerns.

The answer does solve the issue, thanks again. I'll "answer my question" in more detail once I have all the build reasons covered and all is working fine.

Thanks a lot and please feel welcome to reach out if there is any new query. Good luck with the works to go!
